# Getting unified history/blame/diff across repositories?

Tags: git, diff, git-blame

For reasons out of my control, I have two repositories (say, "R" and "S"), and code was moved from one repository to another. More specifically:

R:

Root ... a (add "code" folder) --- b (changes in "code") ... f (remove "code") ...

S:

Root ... a (add "code" removed from Rf) ... d (changes in "code") ...

Is there any way to easily:

- get a diff of the "code" pathspec between the repos, as if Rf and Sa are combined (and since they "cancel" each other out, didn't happen)? In other words, view a diff of "code" between Rb and Sd?
- view a "git blame" so to speak across repositories?

I am aware that theoretically I could filter-branch, pull that code out into a submodule, and reconstruct it, but such an occurrence has happened enough that doing so isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Git works with *commits*, not files.  This makes your "get a diff" question easy, or even trivial: simply *fetch the commits* from one repository (or a clone thereof) to another.  Fetching does not make any *new* commits, it just adds to the current repository all the commits that are in the fetched-from repository.  So now you have, in the repository you're working in—a clone of either R or S—all of the R *and* S commits in a single repository, and now you can `git diff` Rb and Sd trivially.

Making `git blame` track backwards from Sa to Rf is harder, but if you're using a sacrificial clone,<sup>1</sup> you can use `git replace --graft` to "glue the histories together", so that Git doesn't really look at commit Sa at all.  Instead, it looks at a replacement Sa' that's made by grafting to Rf as its parent.  That's still not *difficult*, it just affects everyone using the clone (hence the need for a sacrificial one).

---

<sup>1</sup>The fetch trick above can be done without a sacrificial clone, as the only thing it costs is disk space.  The replace trick affects all users of the repository and thus is often unsuitable.